Host name resolution fails on Fedora 39 system
One of my Fedora systems will often fail to do DNS resolution. Both ping host.ext and nslookup host.ext fail.
When I edit /etc/resolv.conf to use nameserver 1.1.1.1 instead of nameserver 127.0.0.53, nslookup works, but ping still fails.
Why is the runtime library not using the nameserver listed in /etc/resolv.conf?
/etc/nsswitch.conf contains
# Generated by authselect
# Do not modify this file manually, use authselect instead. Any user changes will be overwritten.
# You can stop authselect from managing your configuration by calling 'authselect opt-out'.
# See authselect(8) for more details.

# In order of likelihood of use to accelerate lookup.
passwd:     files sss systemd
shadow:     files
group:      files sss systemd
hosts:      files myhostname resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
services:   files sss
netgroup:   files sss
automount:  files sss

aliases:    files
ethers:     files
gshadow:    files
networks:   files dns
protocols:  files
publickey:  files
rpc:        files

How do I fix that?
How do I persuade the local named to forward its requests to an external name server?
Linux has acquired all these little "helpful" modules, but it seems to me they just obfuscate situations such as these.

What is the content of /etc/nsswitch.conf (add it in question)?

# Do not modify this file manually, use authselect instead. Any user changes will be overwritten, by the way! It tells you which man page to read, because the developers knew it would confuse users who grew up with the file you're manually modifying. The file that Romeo asks for is mentioned therein (though I think a bit of a broader introduction to what is being solved here would have done the man page well)

(by the way, your TDMoIP bridges are way cool, this is valuable technology; you might find OCTOI to be an interesting project, especially the bandwidth-efficient TDMoIP proposal that they've developed, together with very affordable hardware to do the clock-recovering E1 synthesis on one side and the COTS computer interface USB on the other side. One can even produce that design and sell it, as long as one sticks to allowing the same to one's customers; it's licensed CERN-OHL-S.)


I have studied authselect, and have found no relief there.
My real problem is that I do not understand how all these "helpful" layers interact.
Some programs read /etc/resolv.conf to figure out which DNS server to call. For example, sendmail -q will do that. So editing /etc/resolv.conf will give temporary relief.
Other programs do not seem to do that ... for example ping <hostname> will continue to fail even after doing this temp fix.
In any case, a reboot sets it back to use 127.0.0.53 which is not working on that machine. So that is my second problem.



was really just meant to highlight why you need to look into /etc/nsswitch,conf; You might find it managed by different daemons (sadly, I don't know from the top of your head which your Linux has, probably resolved?)



We have discontinued our TDMoIP bridges. We have less than one inquiry per year for this. I think we kept them alive longer than anyone else, and it bugs me that I cannot find anyone to refer those interested parties to.



That is a bit sad :( OK, I don't know how much the company sysmocom, which financially and personally sponsors a good part of the OSMOCOM projects, of which the aforementioned TDMoIP network is, has commercial interest in helping TDM-dependent users, but I know the owner is pretty interested in keeping these technologies alive; there's a somewhat active community of people that do crazy things like buying used building-sized Siemens digital exchanges, so in case you're really longing for people to at least talk to your would-be customers, maybe some of these people could do that.


I have also studied resolved. And even that small helper has multiple components, not well explained how they work together.
I learned the most from man systemd-resolved(8) and man resolved.conf.
But I still have no clue why lookups via the "fake" name server return "Temporary failure in name resolution" (SERVFAIL).

Can I just turn the fake resolver off, and let /etc/resolv.conf point to an outside resolver? Maybe remove the whole fake resolver by removing some module via dnf remove?

I suspect that this is related to the fact that the system (a raspberry pi 4) came up with a very old time after a reboot. The raspberry does not have a hardware clock.
I tried to dnf install ntp so I would have ntpdate available, but dnf said "no match".
But systemctl enable systemd-timesyncd did seem to allow me to establish time synchronization.

The fix was simple, but surprising:
systemctl enable systemd-timesyncd

In its default state, Fedora does not install the real BIND nameserver, but runs a stub nameserver on IP address 127.0.0.53 (where a real BIND instance would be on 127.0.0.1).
That stub server does not work when the system time is wildly out of whack.
Fedora does not run a full NTP service, but systemd has a simplified version. However, that simplified ntp service is not enabled by default, and since Raspberry PI does not seem to have a hardware clock, it often comes up with a bad time.
After applying the above fix, I was able to perform an in-place Fedora version upgrade, which I could not do before.
dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=39
dnf system-upgrade reboot


oh! Wonderful! I've learned something today :)
